# Проблемы с QTime C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть конструктор для класса, в который передается начальное время:

```
map_viewer::map_viewer(QTime *startTime)
{
    _startTime = startTime;

    _tm = new QLabel(_startTime->toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    _layout = new QGridLayout();
    _layout->addWidget(_tm, 3, 2);
}
```

где `_startTime` - `QTime*`, `_tm` - `QLabel*` и `_layout` - `QGridLayout*`. Все заданы в заголовочном. Вызывается конструктор вот так:

```
QTime startTime = datasource->get_start_time();
map_viewer(&startTime);
```

После выполнения конструктора `_tm` имеет нормальный вид, отображает то, что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но сразу после того, как программа выходит из конструктора, почему-то, переменная _startTime принимает invalid value. То есть, пытаюсь изменить значение `_tm` в одном из слотов:

```
_tm->setText(_startTime->addMSecs(param.getTime()).toString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

и получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если попытаться вывести `_startTime->msec()` где либо, кроме конструктора, получаю `-1`, что значит, что `_startTime` имеет недопустимое время. При этом, _startTime не изменяться совершенно нигде, исключительно задается в конструкторе и *используется* в слоте.

Совершенно не имею понятия, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QTime startTime = datasource->get_start_time();
map_viewer(&startTime);
```

В этом месте вы передаете указатель на временный объект. Когда область видимости переменной `startTime` заканчивается - он автоматический разрушается.
Соответственно переменная `_startTime`  в классе `map_viewer` содержит указатель на разрушенную память.

Копируйте время в конструктор по значению или по ссылке.

```
map_viewer::map_viewer(QTime startTime)
```

или лучше так

```
 map_viewer::map_viewer(const QTime &startTime)
```

Но при этом к классе map_viewer тип переменной _startTime  нужно изменить с `QTime*` на `QTime`

Ну и конечно изменить вызов конструктора на такой:

```
QTime startTime = datasource->get_start_time();
map_viewer(startTime);
```

Или даже так:

```
map_viewer(datasource->get_start_time());
```